# Android WebView getContentHeight() doesnt return the correct value

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview

I have a requirement where I display a WebView with a checkbox beneath it. The checkbox is initially in disabled state. Only when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the webview , the checkbox is enabled. I do this by extending Webview class and writing my onScrollChanged listener as below:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int left, int top, int oldLeft, int oldTop) {
     if ( (getContentHeight() - (top + getHeight())) <= mMinDistance )
     {
         Log.i("MYACT","content height: "+getContentHeight()+" top: "+top+" Height: "+getHeight()+" minDistance: "+mMinDistance);
         Log.i("MYACT", "Reached bottom");
         mOnBottomReachedListener.onBottomReached(this);
     }
     else{
         Log.i("MYACT","content height: "+getContentHeight()+" top: "+top+" Height: "+getHeight()+" minDistance: "+mMinDistance);
         Log.i("MYACT", "Not at bottom");
         mOnBottomReachedListener.onNotAtBottom(this);
     }
     super.onScrollChanged(left, top, oldLeft, oldTop);
}
```

The problem is the condition

> (getContentHeight() - (top + getHeight())) <= mMinDistance) //mMinDistance is 0 in my case

is satisfied even before i scroll down to the bottom of the page. As you can see, I tried printing the values of each in log and found that the parameter **"top"** sometimes exceeds the value **"getContentHeight"**.

Sample log values:

> 08-14 11:28:19.401: I/MYACT(1075): content height: 3020 top: 3861
>   Height: 416 minDistance: 0

How can i make avoid this scenario in this case? Should i use a different way of checking whether i have scrolled down to the bottom of the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the issue with this after some research. Webview usually scales the web page based on the screen size and then renders it. It usually zooms the page so that it doesn't look too small in the phone. You can get this scale factor by using the method **getScale()**

So, in my case, i would use the following condition to check whether end of page has been reached

> (getContentHeight()*getScale() - (top + getHeight())) <= mMinDistance)
>   //mMinDistance is 0 in my case

Comment: getScale() is deprecated. To get the page height you have to go through js. You can call js on the page with `view.loadUrl("javascript:" + js)` and you can read results by adding a javascript interface to your setup. No need to modify the website.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves values returned by `getContentHeight()` may depend on implementation of a `WebView` and its rendering mode (software/hardware). But I'm not sure. Perhaps [this talk](https://developers.google.com/events/io/2012/sessions/gooio2012/122/) at Google IO will help you more in this question.

But generally speaking it's always hard and tricky to mix `WebView` with other views, especially when it comes to scrolling.

So my advice would be to put your checkbox into HTML displayed by the `WebView`. You have pretty much options of doing that like injecting some additional HTML code before passing it to `loadData()` method or invoking JavaScript with `loadUrl("javascript:whatever();")`, which can modify the initial DOM structure.

As a rule I do not put other views to Activity window when I have to deal with a `WebView` there.